# LibreOffice Calc/Writer: How to get the dates for specifc weekdays per month?

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer

I'm stuck with a problem in LibreOffice Calc or Writer:

I try to get a table of dates for every Monday, Wednesday and Friday per month, something that I can load every new month wich sets the dates automatically so I just have to print the page on paper. :)

In Writer the fieldcommand for date can't obviously do the job (it only can be set to a fix date, the today's date or +offset as far as I can see).

In Calc I tried it with the autofill but that obviously works for the first 3 days only.

I might add that I'm lost with Excel/Calc formulas...

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If cell `C1` contains a date, then this formula will give you the date of the first Monday in the month:

```
=MOD(DAY(C1)-WEEKDAY(C1,2)+1,7)
```

So for example, if the date in `C1` is `19th December 2012`, then the formula will produce `3`, because the 3rd is the first Monday in December 2012.

To create the full date of the first Monday, you can use:

```
=DATE(YEAR(C1),MONTH(C1),MOD(DAY(C1)-WEEKDAY(C1,2)+1,7))
```

This will result in `05/12/2012` (depending on your date format) - the first Monday

Lets say this is in cell `A4`.  To populate the rest of the days, you need to add +2 for Wednesday, then +2 for Friday, then +3 for the following Monday.  It is easiest to do this manually:

`A5` would be `=A4+2`
`A6` would be `=A5+2`
`A7` would be `=A6+3`

Then you can repeat this down the spreadsheet for the remainder of the month.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That looks pretty good to me, that way I can change just the date of the sheet to get the whole month changed. Great! I played with "=DATE(YEAR(TODAY());12;3)" and added in the next cells for all three days a +7, worked too but your way is far more convinient, thanks! :)

Comment: Hm, after I made a new sheet I get an error 501 now. I just translated it to german: =DATUM(JAHR(C1),MONAT(C1),mod(TAG(C1)-WOCHENTAG(C1,2)+1,7)) but Calc changes the cell-ID of the weekday to C10... why?: "=DATUM(JAHR(C1),MONAT(C1),mod(TAG(C1)-WOCHENTAG(C10,2)+1,7))"

Answer (score 0):

Paul's answer above got me close, but fails when Monday is last day of the previous month (MOD returning 0).

For example September 2015; his formula returns 0, which means 31/aug/2015 as first monday of the month.

I'm using 1 as parameter to weekday, and then adding 1, and it returns the correct day for all months in 2015 (all possible month-end-combinations).

```
=MOD(DAY(C1)-WEEKDAY(C1,1)+1,7)+1
```